# Exception System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember when calling Interop method from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

When I try to open connection for SAP by using Interop, I am getting an error:

> System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember

But the same is working fine when I am using it from Windows standalone application.

Please help or give your suggestions, it will be helpful.

Comment: Inner exception i am getting is bad variant